# What is the time complexity difference between this two python code?

Tags: python, string

I want to do a string assignment in python. However, in python, 'str' object does not support item assignment. 
If I want to do this assignment, `s[head] = s[tail]`, I come up with two ideas:
1.
`s[:head]+s[tail]+s[(head+1):tail]+s[head]+s[(tail+1):]` 
2.

```
temp = list(s)
temp[head] = temp[tail]
s = ''.join(temp)
```

My question is what's the time complexity between these two? When I try some large examples I find that the second solution is faster than the first one, but I don't know why. Could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: They return different values: the first swaps, the second copies.

Comment: Can you show (or describe or show generating code) some of those "large examples" where the second solution is faster?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That's an example from Leetcode....If I use the first one it will be exceed the limited time.. but the second one works.. That's a really long example.... And I cannot copy to the this comment...Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+` to concatenate 2 strings a new string object has to be allocated and the 2 source strings have to be copied to it.

So in your first option, you are creating 5 new strings via slicing, then 4 more strings are created during the concatenation operations. That's 9 string allocation and copy operations in total, and then the 8 intermediate strings need to get de-allocated.

In your second option, you create a list from a string, modify one of the list items, and join the resulting list. The `str.join` method is more efficient than one-by-one concatenation because it does it in two phases. On the first phase it scans the strings in the list to determine the total length required for the destination string, allocates that string and then on the second phase it scans the list again to copy the string data across. (FWIW, this makes passing a list comprehension to `.join` more efficient than passing it an equivalent generator expression, because `.join` has to run the gen exp into a list in order to perform its 2 scans).

String concatenation has been optimised since Python 2.5 (IIRC) to improve the speed of `a = a + b` and `a = b + a` concatenations, but there's not much that can be done for more general cases, and even with the simple cases I just mentioned it's much slower than using `.join` when the strings have length greater than 1000 or so.

However, the exact speed of these operations depends on the version of Python that you're using. And of course, to fairly compare `+` vs `.join` we need t timethem performing the same operations, which your algorithm *doesn't* do.

As Stefan notes in the comments, for your algorithm `.join` may actually be slower, even for large strings. The bottom line is: be aware of the general Python idioms when coding, but general rules are no substitute for measurements. So do speed tests of the actual code operating on typical data, running on your software + hardware. And when practical, use the latest version of Python. (OTOH, some string operations can actually be faster on Python 2, since they're done using ASCII / Latin1 byte strings instead of full Unicode strings).

Comment: *"much slower than using .join when the strings have length greater than 1000 or so"*. I don't think so. I just did a [**test**](http://pastebin.com/TRZMcbfb) and the `.join` solution was over 100 times **slower** (about 12.8 seconds versus about 0.08 seconds for the other solution).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Really? I must admit I've upgraded from Python 2.6.6 to Python 3.6.0 since last time I did timeit tests on this stuff... OTOH, the OP also found `.join` to be faster on large data. But I guess I should modify my answer...

Comment: @StefanPochmann your strings **do not have strings of length greater than 1000**, you have **one hundred thousand strings** of exactly **one single character**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No, I have **one** string of length 100000.

Comment: @PM2Ring I had tried it with Python 3.5.2 and now tried 2.7.12, the results were similar (about 0.09 seconds for string addition and 14.6 seconds for `join`). And I'm not at all surprised. Turning the string into a list of one-char strings and back is quite costly. Creating substrings and concatenating strings is quite fast. I suspect the OP misrepresented what they were doing. Maybe they did **many** modifications of the string between the conversion to list and back.

Comment: @StefanPochmann As Antti said, with strings of that huge length, then the slicing approach is doing far less work than the `list` / `join` approach, so this isn't really a fair comparison of the speed of `+` vs `.join` in general. But of course it _is_ relevant to the OP's algorithm.

Comment: @StefanPochmann FWIW, I originally only glanced briefly at your code & didn't notice that the test string was so large. OTOH, even with much smaller strings, the list / join is slower. So I wonder what's going on with the OP's actual code for them to notice such a speed change.

Comment: @PM2Ring Not sure how you're reading that into Antti's comment. About fairness: You're the one who said it's for long strings :-). But I tested length 1000 now and `.join` was still about 12 times *slower*. With length 100 about 3 times *slower*, and with length 10 they're about equally fast.

Comment: @PM2Ring I just read your fourth paragraph again. Are you saying you in general expect `''.join([a, b])` to be faster than `a + b` for two strings `a` and `b`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, and especially not if you're doing `a = a + b` or `a = b + a`. However, if `seq` is a (large) list of large strings, then `dest = ''.join(seq)` is better than `dest = ''` `for s in seq: dest += s`. That test is fair because we're comparing apples with apples.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok. Your text just doesn't sound like what you just said but like what I had just said. Not sure about that test being fair and apples-vs-apples, as it is misusing `+=` in an inappropriate way.